# Surface Reconstruction given point cloud and surface normals

Tags: algorithm, math, surface, point-clouds

I have a .xyz file that has irregularly spaced points and gives the position and surface normal (ie XYZIJK). Are there algorithms out there that can reconstruct the surface that factor in the IJK vectors? Most algorithms I have found assume that surface normals aren't known.

This would ultimately be used to plot surface error data (from the nominal surface) using python 3.x, and I'm sure I will have many more follow on questions once I find a good reconstruction algorithm.

Comment: Just to point out that for some surfaces (e.g. the dimpled surface of a golf ball, or possibly the surface of an orange) the surface normals may change too quickly to be very useful.

Comment: Some sample data or at least plot so we see the data properties? The easiest way is to reorder the points to a 2D surface grid topology and then create the mesh by joining neighbor points as triangles ... btw you want mesh or regular set of points as output ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The state of the art right now is [Poisson Surface Reconstruction](http://www.cs.jhu.edu/~misha/MyPapers/SGP06.pdf) and [its screened variant](http://www.cs.jhu.edu/~misha/MyPapers/ToG13.pdf). Code for both is available, e.g. under http://www.cs.jhu.edu/~misha/Code/PoissonRecon/Version8.0/. It is also implemented in MeshLab if you want to take a quick look.

If you want to take a look at other methods, check out [this STAR](http://lgg.epfl.ch/publications/2014/reconstar/paper.pdf). Page three has a table of a couple of approaches and their inputs.